# Scaling: Server-Side vs Client-Side Rendering

Tags: architecture, microservices

I've seen a lot of posts about SSR vs CSR but none of them touch on how this speed changes from a small application to a large one serving millions of users.

Also, speed might not be the only concern. How do the two compare when you factor in:

1. Enterprise integration
2. Multiple client types e.g. Native mobile and desktop apps
3. When changing the API (updating or adding new end points) you will have to take the server down and that also takes down your SSR rendering webapp

Could someone please shed some light on this situation?

Many Thanks,
Clement

Answer (score 2):

Both approaches have advantages and disadvantages. The answer changes according to your server. The client side rendering lightens the server side job while saves some time from clients rendering time. If you have server power then it is best practice to follow but as users increase the load on the server will be increased too. At that point you may decide according to your server.

On both you can make enterprise entegrations.

On both you can handle different client types.
on csr or ssr you can use different bffs(backend for frontend) to create the required data but only difference you decide is that it will be rendered or not?

The thirt one is one of the disadvantages of ssr.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for elaborating on all the points above. I think I get it now. Provided the constraints of the system, either one could be better. The third one being a disadvantage is a real letdown though.

Answer (score 0):

I can comment on point #2 specifically.  If you're dealing with multiple client types (web, desktop, mobile), something like a Two Step View can help - define the logical structure of the page server-side, send that to the client in a format like JSON or XML, and then get the client to render the view in the appropriate format.

http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/twoStepView.html

Comment: Oh, I didn't know you could do that. I'll have a look into that. Thank you :)